# sails not lifting on heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, sails.js

Been trying for hours to get my sails app to lift on heroku. Currently running

```
`web: sails lift --silly`
```

from the Procfile.

My production.js file looks like this

```
`connections: {
 subzapp_db: {

  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  host: process.env.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL,
  user: process.env.CLEARDB_USER,
  password: process.env.JAWSDB_PASS,
  database: process.env.CLEARDB_NAME

   }

  },
```

and my models.js

`module.exports.models = {
  migrate: 'drop',
  connection: 'subzapp_db'
    };`

```
`slug compilation finished 
Dec 08 17:33:54 subzapp heroku/web.1:  State changed from crashed to starting 
Dec 08 17:34:09 subzapp heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `sails lift --silly` 
Dec 08 17:34:11 subzapp app/web.1:  Starting app... 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:  Setting Node environment... 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:  Loading app config... 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:  Exposing global variables... (you can  disable this by modifying the properties in `sails.config.globals`) 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:  events.js:141 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:        ^ 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 67.214.212.101:12345 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11) 
   Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20) 
Dec 08 17:34:12 subzapp app/web.1:    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as     oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
```

`
I'm using the Cleardb mysql add-on. I've tried the production js file with just the database url and a million other things. Really really stuck. I also tried changing to jawsdb with the same error. 
This is working fine on my local machine. 
Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ECONNREFUSED means that your DB access failed. Probably bad user/password, wrong database name or address. Double-check those values!